# failed to load database information

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a desktop application that was migrated from .Net 1.0 to .Net 4.0. The application is using Crystal Reports and ttx files as the data definition files. The actual database queries happens in business objects and the data are set using SetDataSource() method.

After I upgraded this to .Net 4.0 (and Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010, version 13), the reports still working great on my developer workstation. But when I installed the application on the test machines I started getting errors like this:

```
Error in File temp_****{****}.rpt: Failed to load database information.
```

Where the asterics signify some kind of GUIDs.

The odd thing is that the reports that I did not touch continue to work. Only the reports where I had to update the data source (TTX file) generate this error.

I am also getting this error:

```
The keycode assembly, BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder.dll, cannot be loaded.
```

but I do not know if this is related.

Answer (score 1):

The Keycoder error is not the problem. That is currently a warning message that seems to have no effect on anything (as best I can tell).

Don't be confused by the GUID stuff either. It's just a temp name that Crystal gives the report object.

The real error there is simply "failed to load database information". Something in your TTX update is at fault.

You might try running the report in Crystal 2008 on the machine giving you the problem. Your report is out-of-sync with the TTX file.