# Failed to load database information error

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

My code works fine and the report opens on my PC. When I try to open the same report from my app on another machine, I get this error. How do I resovle this?

> Failed to load database information. Error in File
>   temp_92bf354f-8e8f-4bb8-adc9-3699bf6fef86
>   996_4916_{76EC69A0-4A21-4077-89D4-12F6242DFCEF}.rpt: Failed to load
>   database information.
>
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Failed to load database
>   information. Error in File temp_92bf354f-8e8f-4bb8-adc9-3699bf6fef86
>   996_4916_{76EC69A0-4A21-4077-89D4-12F6242DFCEF}.rpt: Failed to load
>   database information.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with SQL Server 2012 and Crystal Report v3_0_16. My PC runs Windows 10 64 bit. I've opened it on a 64-bit machine and 32-bit machine, but both get the same error.

Comment: Are you try install CR runtime on your "other" computer?

Comment: Yes i install CR runtime but still same error

Comment: Version 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: 32 and 64 and still same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [failed to load database information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522389/failed-to-load-database-information)

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this issue????